# Is by design, Drupal headless?

Tags: 9

If I understood correctly, "decoupling" a content management system means separating backend from frontend (having two "modules" for each under the same "program").

If I understood correctly, "headlessing" a content management system is making it to be possible to supply content to at least two different front-end interfaces at once ("two different programs" as may appear to an end user).

I would assume that by design, Drupal is not decoupled because it **does** have built in JavaScript (quick edit for a node, for example) but by design is it headless?

Comment: "_Drupal is not decoupled because it does have built in JavaScript almost anywhere_" 

Comment: @leymannx isn't at least one case of using JavaScript in Drupal GUI would mean lack of decoupling backend from frontend.

Answer (score 2):

Headed means there is a GUI (Graphic User Interface). Headless means a system without that.
Drupal can be run headless - there are headless distributions out there that can be used as the back-end for apps or a React site or whatnot. However, by default it's headed - Drupal core has a GUI out of the box.
Decoupling refers to separating the head (GUI) and the back-end. Drupal is decoupled in that it separates the front end from the back-end.

> Drupal is by design not decoupled because it does have built in
> JavaScript almost anywhere

Drupal is decoupled, and it does have an extensive, powerful JavaScript API that ships with core: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Answer (score 1):

Drupal can be used decoupled, and as new features are added to Drupal 9, support for decoupling is given high priority under the [API-First Initiative](https://www.drupal.org/about/strategic-initiatives/api-first) (ensure APIs are provided that allow programmers to select the parts of Drupal they want to use, and replace other parts as needed with custom solutions).

Historically, Drupal 7 + older versions are NOT decoupled (although older versions can e used headlessly with contributed modules), but starting from Drupal 8, decoupled use is supported by Drupal core itself.

Yes, Drupal does provide a frontend-- but this frontend is provided through modules that can be disabled.  So Drupal can be used decoupled because it does not force you to use its UI; you can disable the Drupal UI and replace it with something else, like a React or Angular app.

**What does headless use actually look like?**

[Contenta](https://www.contentacms.org/) is a headless Drupal distribution that can give you an idea of how to set up Drupal for headless use.

To actually get at your content, Drupal provides support for JSON:API and REST in Core, and GraphQL is available via a contributed module.  The JSON:API support is particularly great because it lets you expose all your content with Drupal permissions intact with very little additional configuration.

However, this is a pretty complex topic; there's a whole book on it:

- [Decoupled Drupal in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484240715)

There's also a great series of tutorials available at [Drupalize.me](https://drupalize.me/series/decoupled-drupal).